How to add date-field in sqlalchemy in "mapped" style?
My current date field:
date: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(DATE, default=date.today)

But postgresql says that this field is required, even though I have set it to default.
P.S. date - datetime.date; DATE - sqlalchemy.DATE

But postgresql says that this field is required -> under what circumstances, or where do you see this?  Note that you are only setting a default at the Python level; at the db level the column is NOT NULL with no default defined unless you define server_default in the SQLAlchemy column definition.

@snakecharmerb, date: Mapped[date] = mapped_column(DATE, server_default=func.current_date()) has worked!!! Thanks

@snakecharmerb, do you know how to set 'False' as default in boolean-field by any chance? My field:
approved: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean, server_default='t'), but it doesn't work. Also, i've tried default=True and server_default=expression.true()

I found that specifically with postgresql, using server_default with sqlalchemy.func is more appropriate. I'm doing this with datetime and can confirm it works:
datetime_added: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(Datetime, server_default=func.now())

I do not know if it will convert to date automatically if you use func.now(). Please comment and let us know if you try this.
